# SQL база и java

Tags: java, sql, сервер

Была предпринята попытка создать простое приложение в целях обучения Java, целью которого была связь с базой данных. Имеется GUI форма, в которой два поля для ввода текста (логин и пароль) и кнопка входа. Код приложения:

```
       import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;


public class formLogin extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        formLogin Start = new formLogin();
    }

    private JButton button2;
    private JButton button1;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JPasswordField passwordField1;
    private JPanel Login;

    public formLogin() {
        setContentPane(Login);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String sql="Select name, passw from main";
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testbd","root","qqq111");
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                    String user = textField1.getText();
                    String pwd = new String (passwordField1.getPassword());
                    while(rs.next()) {
                        String name = rs.getString("name");
                        String passw = rs.getString("passw");
                        if ((user.equals(name)) && (pwd.equals(passw)))
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nice");
                    }
                }
                catch (SQLException err){

                    System.out.println( err.getMessage());
                }
                catch (Exception ess)
                {
                    System.out.println( ess.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });



        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });


        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Форма работает, но нет связи с бд, насколько я понимаю. Потому что при любом содержимом текстовых полей у меня высвечивается окно из Exception ess. Имя базы - testbd. Таблица с логинами - name , паролями - passwd. LoginMySQL - rootm password - qqq111. Не подскажите, что я делаю не так? Благодарю!

Comment: Вопросы подразумевают повторный просмотр пользователями. Ваш вопрос с "длинным" кодом и ответ на него решает только Вашу проблему. Нужно писать вопросы так, чтобы они были ещё кому-то интересны...-1

Answer (score 1):

Помог MqSQL Connector, скачанный с официального сайта.